# Linux Запрет на удаления файлов

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, bash, администрирование

Запрет на удаления /test/info1

```
/test/info1
```

Comment: Индивидуальный запрет на файлы с помощью `chattr` - не практичный , не все файловые системы это поддерживают. Проще сделать директорию с правом только для чтения для таких файлов.

Comment: chattr +i  /test/info1 
Задачу мою выполнил

Comment: rm: невозможно удалить 'info1': Операция не позволена

Comment: Все ок ... Проблем не вижу я

Comment: Индивидуальный запрет на файлы с помощью chattr - не практичный , не все файловые системы это поддерживают. Проще сделать директорию с правом только для чтения для таких файлов.  Это полный бред !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!   рут удалит содрж.. деректории

Comment: `$ chattr +i test    
    chattr: Operation not permitted while setting flags on test`

Comment: Разобрался, `root` - может поставить флаг, а удалить файл - нет.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Атрибуты на файл

```
chattr +i  /test/info1
chattr -i  /test/info1   (Убрать Атрибуты)
```

Comment: Спасибо буду  тестить